# Issues uploading/downloading files in akka-http/akka-streams

Tags: amazon-s3, akka-stream, akka-http, alpakka

I'm trying to use akka-streams and akka-http and the alpakka library to download/upload files to Amazon S3.  I am seeing two issues which might be related...

- I can only download very small files, the largest one 8kb.
- I can't upload larger files. It fails with the message

  Error during processing of request: 'Substream Source has not been
  materialized in 5000 milliseconds'. Completing with 500 Internal 
  Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, 
     provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
     akka.stream.impl.SubscriptionTimeoutException: 
  Substream Source has not been materialized in 5000 milliseconds

Here are my routes

```
pathEnd {
           post {
             fileUpload("attachment") {
               case (metadata, byteSource) => {
                 val writeResult: Future[MultipartUploadResult] = byteSource.runWith(client.multipartUpload("bucketname", key))
                 onSuccess(writeResult) { result =>
                   complete(result.location.toString())
                 }
               }

             }
           }

         } ~

     path("key" / Segment) {
            (sourceSystem, sourceTable, sourceId) =>
              get {
                val result: Future[ByteString] = 
         client.download("bucketname", key).runWith(Sink.head)
                onSuccess(result) {
                  complete(_)
                }
              }
          }
```

Trying to download a file of say 100KB will end up fetching a truncated version of the file usually of size around 16-25Kb
    Any help appreciated

Edit: For the download issue, I took Stefano's suggestion and got

```
[error]  found   : akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed]
[error]  required: akka.http.scaladsl.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
```

This made it work

```
complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, client.download("bucketname", key).runWith(Sink.head)))
```

Answer (score 2):

1) On the download issue: by calling

```
val result: Future[ByteString] = 
         client.download("bucketname", key).runWith(Sink.head)
```

you are streaming **all** the data from S3 into memory, and then serve the result.

Akka-Http as streaming support that allows you to stream bytes straight from a source, without buffering them all in memory. More info on this can be found in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html#source-streaming). Practically, this means the `complete` directive can take a `Source[ByteString, _]`, as in

```
...
get {
  complete(client.download("bucketname", key))
}
```

2) On the upload issue: you can try to tweak Akka HTTP `akka.http.server.parsing.max-content-length` setting:

```
# Default maximum content length which should not be exceeded by incoming request entities.
# Can be changed at runtime (to a higher or lower value) via the `HttpEntity::withSizeLimit` method.
# Note that it is not necessarily a problem to set this to a high value as all stream operations
# are always properly backpressured.
# Nevertheless you might want to apply some limit in order to prevent a single client from consuming
# an excessive amount of server resources.
#
# Set to `infinite` to completely disable entity length checks. (Even then you can still apply one
# programmatically via `withSizeLimit`.)
max-content-length = 8m
```

Resulting code to test this would be something along the lines of:

```
  withoutSizeLimit {
    fileUpload("attachment") {
      ...
    }
  }
```